# ProgressMonitorInputStream not working?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying a simple socket based file transfer program to include a ProgressMonitorInputStream, my file transfer is working fine. But the progressMonitor never shows up.
I am sending a file from server to client, when it connects, my file is getting transfered perfectly, but just don't understand why the ProgressMonitor doesn't come up.

I searched some examples, they used 'this' instead of 'new Jframe()' in PMIS, but since I was inside main(), it didn't allow me to do that.

```
//client
InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(
new ProgressMonitorInputStream(new JFrame(),"reading",is));
while ((read = bis.read(buffer,0,buffer.length)) != -1) {
//read from socket...now write to file 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
I searched some examples, they used 'this' instead of 'new Jframe()' in PMIS
```

You have re_read tutorial about [How to Use Progress Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html), there is basic description for [ProgressMonitorInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitorInputStream.html)

Swing is [single threaded](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) and if you want to move with `progress`, then you have to redirect this `Stream` to the `BackroundTask`, tutorial about `JProgressBar` implelemnts [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), another options is wrap that to the `Runnable#Thread`, but in this case output to the GUI must be wrapped into `invokeLater()`

Comment: i didn't understood SwingWorker on the tuts, but if i use 'this', i get an error that, the constructor....not defined, it is not accepting an object of my Class.

Comment: i am not using any window, i mean all my output comes on console, doesn't that PMIS will need Jframe's object to draw?

Comment: @Nikhar Sharma :-) please use code from tutorial, just inside SwingWorker class change with your code :-)